# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, cmake, gfortran

I'm getting this error when I try to build this software available in GitHub (https://github.com/fabienbaron/bsmem). I'm using cmake to build it.

```
 2 warnings generated.
 [ 33%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/bsmem.dir/bsmemf.f.o 
 [ 50%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bsmem.dir/free_fits.c.o 
[ 66%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bsmem.dir/read_fits.c.o 
[ 83%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/bsmem.dir/vector.f.o 
[100%] Linking C executable ../../bin/bsmem Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "_mecopy_", referenced from:
          _icf_ in bsmemf.f.o
          _tricf_ in bsmemf.f.o   "_meinit_", referenced from:
          _bsmem in bsmem.c.o   "_mem4_", referenced from:
          _bsmem in bsmem.c.o   "_memset_", referenced from:
          _bsmem in bsmem.c.o   "_meswap_", referenced from:
          _udiag_ in bsmemf.f.o   "_movie4_", referenced from:
          _bsmem in bsmem.c.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 
collect2: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 make[2]: *** [../bin/bsmem] Error 1 make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/bsmem.dir/all] 
Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `_mecopy_`? What is that? Where do you find this function? Do you really mean `memcpy`? The same with the rest of the symbols, what are they? And where are they defined (implemented)?

Comment: They are functions, you can find them in here :
https://github.com/fabienbaron/bsmem/tree/master/src

Comment: The problem looks like **project-specific**. The only [issue](https://github.com/fabienbaron/bsmem/issues/1) for the project contains the error message which looks very similar to yours. You may wait while the project's developer fixes the issue. If you want to fix the problem by yourself, we could help you. But in this case you need to show some efforts for fixing the problem. Note that Stack Overflow is not a support site for 3d-party projects.

Comment: Tsyvarev. I am the one who reported the issue for the project few days ago. I'm trying to fix the problem. I would be grateful if you can help me. 
I think there are two ways to fix this problem:
1- Using the right library to link correctly, because I think this a linking issue. But I don't know what's this library.
2- Modify the code and rewrite it but since I don't know what the functions... so I don't think this is gonna be helpful.